# Does smoothness imply boundedness? Evans PDE chapter 2 Problem 18

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

In problem 18, 
[enter link description here](http://www.math.umn.edu/~robt/docs/evans_solutions.pdf)

1) I am having difficulty in extracting information in deciding the bounded for $g$ and $h$. In particular, to conclude $g$, $Dg$, $h$ $Dh$ are bounded by some constants, is it enough to assume $g,h$ are smooth? Otherwise, are there any examples of smooth function which are not necessarily bounded?

2) All I understood is, smoothness implies infinite differentiability, but does differentialbility guarantee boundedness, if not, any counter examples?

Thanks for any helps!

Comment: Keyword there is "compact support"

Comment: yes, my teacher told me so today, just couldn't find such things in books and so ask for comfort...

Comment: Compact support + smooth on the whole space. Another example is $1/x$ on $(0,1)$. It is smooth but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smoothness certainly does not imply boundedness.  The function $f(x) = e^x$ is smooth (analytic, even) but is unbounded along with all of its derivatives.  In the link you provided the assumption is that the functions are smooth and compactly supported.  The key is the last assumption.  We know from real analysis that any continuous function with compact support must be bounded.  Indeed, to see this we just use the extreme value theorem.  Since all of the derivatives are also compactly supported, all of the derivatives are bounded.

Comment: yes, you are right, my teacher drawn me a smooth curvy line infinitely long and told me we cannot find a bound for it, but if the function lies on a compactly supported set, then we can definitely find a bound. I asked this question because I am still at a preliminary stage of getting used to be careful about such things which I have no experience about. Thank you

Comment: can you provide an explicit example please, as i requested in the question?

Comment: My second sentence above has the counterexample.  The exponential function is smooth but unbounded.  The same goes for its derivatives since they all equal the exponential.